# kendoColorPicker created dynamically - how to obtain element id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have six kendoColorPicker objects initialized in a loop ([see jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/kp2C9/127/)). When a color is choosen in one of them, I need to get its element id in the change event.

I tried with the below but it does not work:

Any ideas?

This is the javascript:

```
    for (var i=1;i<=6;i++){
             $("#picker0"+i).kendoColorPicker({
                  value: "#ffffff",
                  change: function(e) {
                    alert($(this).attr('id'));
                }
             });
    }
```

and the input elements declaration:

```
    <input id="picker01" /> <input id="picker02" /> <input id="picker03" />
    <input id="picker04" /> <input id="picker05" /> <input id="picker06" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get from the sender  `e` object of it:

```
change: function(e) {
            alert($(e.sender.element).attr("id"))
        }
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/kp2C9/132/

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with kendo, but try binding the change event separately

```
   for (var i=1;i<=6;i++){
        $("#picker0"+i).kendoColorPicker({
            value: "#ffffff"
        })
        .on("change",function(){
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
        });
    }
```

Updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kp2C9/131/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works, however Ehsan's answer is more Kendo-oriented.